# Converting binary string to binary

Tags: rust

I have binary strings:

```
let x = "0b101101111";
let y = "0b111111";
```

How do I convert the string to binary to be able to find the sum?

this works:

```
let x = 0b101101111;
let y = 0b111111;
println!("x + y = {:b} ", x + y);
// x + y = 110101110
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the string always begins with the constant `0b` characters, then you can simply strip those and read the actual digits using [`from_str_radix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i64.html#method.from_str_radix).

```
let x = "0b101101111";
let x_num = i64::from_str_radix(x[2..], 2).unwrap();
```